# Show result of long task after a ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have an application which runs a long task and returns a value. While the task is running, a `ProgressDialog` shows the progress. After the task is done I want to show the result in a `TextView`. I run the task in a FutureTask.
My problem is that if I try to get the result, the `.get()` method of FutureTask blocks the UI Thread and I don't see the `ProgressDialog` (the `TextView` displays the result propertly).

My code for the task (pool is ExecutorService):

```
final FutureTask<String> future = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {  
    @Override  
    public String call() {  
        return myLongTask();  
    }  
});  
pool.execute(future);
```

And afterwards I call `updateProgressBar()` in a `Runnable` which updates the `ProgressDialog` with a `Handler`:

```
Runnable pb = new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {  
        myUpdateProgressBar();  
    }  
};  
pool.execute(pb);
```

Now I'm getting the result, which blocks the UI Thread preventing the `ProgressDialog` to show up:

```
String result = future.get()
```

If I try to put the result inside the updateProgressBar() method (by passing the future as a parameter) after the ProgressDialog dismisses, an Exception is thrown:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? (I've heard about AsyncTasks but I can't figure out how to use them propertly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you need either an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`/`Handler` combination in order to not block the UI.

Neither approach is that tricky, and there are some good guides around that lay out how to do them.  Here are some links that I'd recommend.

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: After reading about AsyncTask (and some examples) I got it working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had similiar problem when implementing ExecutorService, the following code block the UI thread and need to be run on a separated thread:

```
String result = future.get()
```

Just create a class extending AsyncTask to handle the `future.get()` method like the following code example:

```
private class FutureTask extends AsyncTask<Future<String>, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected PhotoToView doInBackground(Future<String>... params) {
        Future<String> f = params[0];
        try {
            return f.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String futureResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(futureResult);

        // this method is run on UI thread
        // do something with the result 
        // or simply hide the progress bar 
        // if you had previously shown one.

    }
}
```

And run the future thread with:

```
FutureTask ft = new FutureTask();
ft.execute(future);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't it seem a little overkill to use an AsyncTask (which in a sense is an alternative to FutureTask) just to get data out of the FutureTask? You'd be better off running it all in the AsyncTask instead

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The `AsyncTask` documentation says that it shouldn't be used for long operations. It recommends using a `FutureTask`.